# Send string from pyserial to arduino

Tags: python, c++, string, arduino

Hello i need to send spotify song name from python to arduino, but arduino receive only numbers like '122', '117' etc. How to send all string? Here is my code

python code:

```
import serial
import time
from SwSpotify import spotify

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

while True:
   print(spotify.song())
   ser.write(spotify.song().encode())
   time.sleep(5)
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h>
#include <Wire.h>

LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcd(0x27); // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display


int incomingByte;     

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setBacklight(255);
  lcd.print("Hello!");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a character use [lcd.write](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalWrite)

> http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LiquidCrystalSerialDisplay
>
> ```
> */
>
> // include the library code:
> #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
>
> // initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
> // with the arduino pin number it is connected to
> const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
> LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
>
> void setup() {
>   // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
>   lcd.begin(16, 2);
>   // initialize the serial communications:
>   Serial.begin(9600);
> }
>
> void loop() {
>   // when characters arrive over the serial port...
>   if (Serial.available()) {
>     // wait a bit for the entire message to arrive
>     delay(100);
>     // clear the screen
>     lcd.clear();
>     // read all the available characters
>     while (Serial.available() > 0) {
>       // display each character to the LCD
>       lcd.write(Serial.read());
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Please read manuals and refer to Arduino's examples and tutorials

Comment: I would like to force if the song name was send the cursor of lcd will be set to next line. How to detect that?

Comment: not sure what happens if you print a newline character `'\n'` but you could also send a terminator character to Arduino and check if you received it. If so you set the cursor to the next line https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalSetCursor    newline would be a good choice.  I wonder, do they have websearch where you live? did you ever do an Arduino tutorial or read the documentation?